# Remove H/H+ from signal bars?

Tags: notification-icons

I know what they mean, but I'm a minimalist and in my defense, it takes up a lot more space than I've seen the other H/H+ icons. So how could I remove it? Majority of the time, I'm not on the web with my phone that much except my breaks at work, so I really don't worry about having this.

[image]

Comment: What model phone is this on? Is it a custom ROM of some kind? I'm fairly certain this is not what it looks like in stock AOSP.

Comment: @keepcalm Yeah, stock ASOP 4.4.4 running on a Moto G 2014 edition.

Comment: Running some kind of Xposed module or something?

Comment: @keepcalm Yeah, as of now. But this has been happening before I even unlocked my boot loader.